# Network render one still image not an animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, network, render-passes

I know it's possible to render an animation in a network by rendering every frame with one PC. **However, I want to render one image.**

I would like to know how.

Should I let **every computer render one different pass**. If so, how?

Or, should I **split the still image in tiles**. (Would I do this with a script, or is there a better way?)

I want to post processing of the image and have **control over the different passes** to blur noise and get rid of fireflies.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "every computer"? Do you mean "with each PC" instead of "with one PC"?

Comment: I edited the grammar as much as possible, however, I think the language barrier may also be contributing to your question's context. Maybe take a look at my edit and try to rephrase the question?

Comment: I want to render one Image. At my computer it takes 20 hours. But i have access to more than one computer. How could i use them to improve my render time.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, yes you could divide the image (tiles) and distribute then to each computer over a network. The fact is, there is no script/function to do that and the overhead for each connection will be something to consider, since will need to send the whole scene anyway to allow the render engine show all reflection, color bleeding, etc...
Another approach, that I am testing right now, is to render a image with a smaller number of samples with different seed for each computer and then, re-assembly them back. This methodology is already covered by others (Kent Trammell, this is the arquive file on [cgcokkie](https://cgcookie.com/archive/rendering-a-single-frame-faster-with-multiple-computers/) or even here [@StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21806/how-to-combine-low-sample-renders).

We can think about this as: For two images generated with different seeds,  let's get pixel[10,10] for instance. On first image the RGB value is (0.34, 0.78, 0.2) and on second image the same pixel[10,10] is (0.32, 0.80, 0.22). None of this values are right or wrong, but we can assume that the best value (or median) will be (0.33, 0.79, 0.21), that is probably more close to right answer for that pixel.

Using this approach, is it possible to write a simple script to load images from a folder, and them find the median value for each pixel and generate a final image.