# Is there any way to augment the previous render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I rendered my scene with 1000 samples and it is still looking grainy. I would like to pass another 1000 samples on top of this render result. When I start a new render Blender starts rendering the new image. Is it possible to tell Blender to reuse the result of the previous render and just run another set of samples on top of it?

Comment: There isn't direct way to do that however this can be done via compositor, answer with corrected math https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21806/how-to-combine-low-sample-renders/21809#21809. More complex solution https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/stacking-cycles-renders-in-the-compositor

Comment: @MrZak could you put this into an answer?

Comment: This is a duplicate in my opinion so I don't answer. You can answer it instead if you think there are any new details as opposed to the linked question or flag the question as duplicate