# Add more samples after render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

If I rendered in cycles with 128 samples for example, is there any way to increase the samples count to 256 and only do the additional 128 samples without starting the rendering all over again?
I'm using version 2.83.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21806/how-to-combine-low-sample-renders

Comment: I don't think that's possible, you'll just have to render it again. Also to change the samples you use the render tab.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/stacking-cycles-renders-in-the-compositor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [Progressive Refine](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#tiles) *(Render Properties > Performance > Tiles)*, set the sample count to a high amount like `10000` and stop the process manually (<kbd>ESC</kbd>) when satisfied.

However, I'd suggest use the [Render Region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html#render-region) feature and drag a rectangle around the darkest spot in the image (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>), set the viewport samples to `0` and wait until the noise is resolved to get an idea how many samples are required and do a full render based on that knowledge.

Comment: Wouldn't adaptive sampling do the work? [Adaptive Sample](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html#adaptive-sampling). Although it's complicated to use and tune

Comment: Nope, just helps to speed up the rendering in general, should be enabled by default IMHO. However, not relevant in this case @HikariTW