# Is it possible to continue rendering an image from that point after it finished rendering by further increasing rendering samples?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

I just finished the rendering. I am not satisfied with the final result. I want to push it further. Is there a way to increase the rendering sample to continue rendering based on this result without starting over again?

Comment: When it is done - it is done ... from what I know ... sorry. Blender has no pause-resume rendering either for now. It just reminds me (time before denser, people used technique to render several images and merging them in post pro to enhance result, so try to search for that.

Comment: ... so probably duplicate? How to combine low sample renders ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21806 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5018/2214

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you rendered the image. During rendering samples are simply averaged, but if you use denoising then AI processes the image. If you rendered an image without denoising with one seed and restarted the render with another seed, you would get different samples so you could just average the two images depending on amount of samples and it would be the same result as if you just continued rendering. They can be simply mixed. It would be ideal to render to lossless EXR format.

[image]

If you have a look, the mix is less noisy than the parts on their own.

The images were rendered with different seeds. Seed number can be changed in Render Properties tab, Sampling panel, Advanced sub-panel:

[image]

This should work with simple 8 bit per channel images as well and the image should improve even if denoising was used, but it might not be exactly the same as just continuing the render. There will probably be some detail loss if you mix images with denoising. Only if you save renders to EXR, you get raw data from render, not altered, compressed or clipped by color management so you can only get exactly same results as if you continue rendering with EXRs.

Comment: And actually the _Denoise_ filter can be used in the compositor on already rendered images as well, of course there is no _Denoising Data_ but it still does a quite good job.

Comment: Yeah, sure, one can definitely use denoising on the combined result and one can also render the denoising data passes to multilayer EXR if they suspect they might need to combine multiple renders, but denoising changes raw data like for example removes fireflies. What are fireflies early in the render may become caustics after a while, so that would mess things up for all the combining business if denoising is used for partial renders.

Comment: Sure... that's not what I meant and I didn't criticize your answer. What I meant is, it is unproblematic to render without denoising for better results in combining afterwards, because even if you want to use denosing on your image you can always do it afterwards, no need to do it on partial renders.