# Splitting a single frame render to multiple separate renders

Tags: rendering

A single frame render with the settings i run takes about 15 hours for me, i want to split that into chunks of lets say 1/4 or 1/8 so that i can shut down my computer at night and render the chunks over multiple days, instead of being forced to have it run til the render is finished, is this possible?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/47274/38953

Comment: related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-can-i-pause-a-render-in-progress-and-then-resume-it-at-a-later-time and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7126/why-is-render-stacking-less-efficient-noisier-than-rendering-normally and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3720/creating-renders-from-image-stacking-using-different-sampling-levels/3723#3723

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52392/resumable-render-for-cycles/52733#52733