# How can I do multiple "renderings" of one scene in one render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have a scene in which I want to reduce noise/fireflies by the method illustrated [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1819/), i.e. rendering twice (or in my case 4 times, but the theory is the same) with lower sample count but different seed and combining the results with blending mode "Darken".

My scene is an animation with ~500 frames so rendering it twice would result in a lot higher used storage. What I'd like to do is tell blender

1. render frame 1 with render seed 1
2. render frame 1 with render seed 2
3. combine those two frames to one using darken
4. combine my compositing nodes to the result of step 3
5. output that as one file
6. repeat for every other frame

it doesn't matter for me if steps 1 and 2 are done at the same time (if that's even possible) or not as I assume the total duration would be the same. Preferably this should work without python scripts since I plan on using a render farm which doesn't support those.

How can I do this?

Blender version used is 3.3.1 but if there's a solution that requires 3.4 updating would be no problem.

Comment: btw I'm not very happy with the title of this question but can't think of something better - suggestions/edits are welcome :)

Comment: are you looking for automating this without python? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/stacking-cycles-renders-in-the-compositor?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The comment by [R M K](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/155551/r-m-k) pointed me in the right direction (thanks!) and I've been able to figure out a solution myself.

What I ended up doing was creating multiple scenes (within the same file) for which I copied all objects and render settings from the original scene and then only gave them a different seed.

In the compositor I then used a node setup like this
[image]

with some other nodes that are not relevant to the denoising behind. I suppose I could also have enabled the other passes (Emit, AO, Depth) in every scene and apply the same process to them but considering that they didn't have any noise/firefly problems I just left them as they are.

During rendering, every scene gets rendered separately<sup>1</sup> and then composited at the end. Since you can easily get away with 1/4 of the original sample count, the overall time needed is pretty much the same.

---

<sup>1</sup> for some reason (maybe just a bug) every scene other than the original doesn't show any progress during rendering (it's just a transparent image) but it still works and after it's finished you can preview those scenes in compositor.