# Increase quality of water render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

Here is my attempt at dropping things into water. Unfortunately it did not turn to out well especially at the bottom right and this is at 900 cycles. Are there any ways apart from increasing the cycles to make it look better? I mostly want to fix the colored spots from the above the lemon.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally assigned another texture to the lemon with default color?

Comment: @stacker the lemon color is fine but how do I get rid of that thing in the bottom right. it is still there at 2000 cycles

Comment: referring to the pink spots? that's just an image texture looking without an actual file value (you haven't chosen the image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what part of your render you are asking about, but here are some possibilities:

[image]

1. This appears to be caused by [internal reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection) of a light source (judging from the lighting, I would say the light source is behind the camera and a little to the left). Try adjusting the lighting in your scene and see if it improves.
2. The fluid simulation appears to be rendered at a low resolution. Try baking at a higher resolution (e.g. start with `100`). If you did bake at high resolution, ensure that the *Render* display option is set to *Final*.
3. It's hard to say what's causing this without looking at your file, but a couple of possibilities are:

   - The geometry of the orange mesh. Ensure that the normals in that area are facing the right way, check for overlapping faces, ensure that there are no holes in the mesh, etc.
   - Bounces. Try increasing the number of *Bounces* in *Render settings > Light paths* (A fast way to increase all bounce related settings is with the presets, try the *Full Global Illumination* preset). This will increase the overall accuracy of the render as well, so you probably want to increase them anyway. Note that more bounces will slow down your render.
4. To help decrease fireflies, see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1703/599). Some techniques mentioned there are:

   - The [*Clamp*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html#clamp-fireflies) option (may or may not be very helpful in this scene, however I thought I would mention it). From the [wiki](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/integrator.html#render-cycles-integrator-no-caustics):

     > This option will clamp all samples to a maximum intensity they can
     >   contribute to the pixel, again to reduce noise at the cost of
     >   accuracy. With value 0.0 this option is disabled; lower values clamp
     >   more light away.
     >
     > If the image has fireflies, there will be samples that contribute very
     >   high values to pixels, and this option provides a way to limit that.
     >   However note that as you clamp out such values, bright colors in other
     >   places where there is no noise will be lost as well. So this is a
     >   balance between reducing the noise and keeping the image from losing
     >   its intended bright colors.
   - Render stacking. See the following posts:

     - [Stacking cycles renders in the compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5017/599)
     - [Creating renders from Image Stacking using different sampling levels](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3720/599)
     - [How can I pause a render in progress and then resume it at a later time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/998/599)
   - [Fake refractive caustics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html#glass-and-transparent-shadows)
   - *[Filter Glossy](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html#caustics-and-filter-glossy)*
   - *[No Caustics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/integrator.html#render-cycles-integrator-no-caustics)* (definitely **not** useful in this scene, as you need the caustics for light to reach the fruit, but again I thought I would mention it anyway)

See the [manual page on reducing noise](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html).