# How do i stop my animation from being cropped out

Tags: rendering, animation, image

I'm having trouble trying to render a YouTube intro, when I render just one frame to test it, it turns out like this:

[image]

I am very new to Blender and just using a template, when I first open the template and play it, the animation runs fine and fills the entire screen instead of being cropped out

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how this can be fixed

**UPDATE:** Added a link to download my blender file if it helps, the issue only happens on a 1080p resolution or higher
https://mega.nz/#!jx1GFRSL!8t3rd3rqqxrC1BvBA34Eaiu3k6D-IEXCwndTZwGc7AI

Comment: Disable *Border Render*, right bellow the *Aspect Ratio* sliders

Comment: i have done that, i just worked out that it only does this when im in 1080p, if i change it to 720p then there are no black borders or anything but i would like the animation to be in 1080p, suggestions??

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the file. Please consider editing your question and [providing a link to your file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgcTb.jpg) if you want a proper answer

Comment: Ive added a link that should be open for download without any passwords, try that :)

Comment: It's certainly something to do with the compositor. Blender crashed on me while trying to render the animation. Does it crop your image in the video too, or only in a single frame render?

Comment: It crops it either way, but only in 1080p or higher, if I change resolution to fit 720p for YouTube its fine but I'd prefer the higher quality

Comment: Please don't delete images from your post, this make it less clear. If you don't want to continue hosting images on your imgur account [upload them with built-in possibility](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194/sites-to-use-for-uploading-images-and-files) right here in question window, thank you.

Comment: I didn't delete them, not sure why they disappeared and not sure why the other one is unavailable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the compositor section, which joins the render with previous fixed dimensions images: varying the dimensions of the renders creates the problem: go to the compositor (Green selections), and everywhere there is an *Image* node (Red) add a scale node (Blue) with both X and Y set to 2.

This must be done also in the big "Nodetree" which is a group of nodes and can be opened selecting it and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> (press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to close). The same for all the "vignette" nodes.

A simpler method is to select the nodes and press <kbd>M</kbd> (mute) to disable them.
If you <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Click</kbd> a node and wait a few seconds to let the compositor calculate, you can inspect the output of every node of the node tree, so you can understand where the problem lies and where is resolved (start from left to right).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help but I literally have no idea what you mean, I've not use blender before and don't understand what your telling me to do, I will try my best to follow these instructions when I get up in the morning, thanks :)

Comment: I muted all the thing you told me too but now the animation looks bad, do I have to not have any of the effects to put it on 1080p

Comment: I muted all the things you told me to but it makes the animation look terrible, no effects or anything, maybe it would be best if I just rendered it in 720p resolution

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, maybe you could fix it for me and give me a link to download it, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of reasons for this.
Most likely, you have a render border (red block) that limits the render zone.

Uncheck Border (as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgcTb.jpg))

[image]

Related: 
[How do I clear the render border?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/how-do-i-clear-the-render-border)

[Can I specify a portion of the image to render in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4852/can-i-specify-a-portion-of-the-image-to-render-in-cycles)

If that didn't work, you could try to adjust the resolution settings, or maybe move the camera around the scene.

Comment: Ive tried removing the border and changing the resolution
This is what the red box looks like when the border is on
https://i.gyazo.com/fa4df3878aececa20fef157323febb70.png

Comment: have you got any other suggestions? i dont know alot about blender so please be specific :)

Comment: What? How is it perfect? I've done what u said and it turns out the same as the top picture

Comment: I added a link to download the .blend file if u want to see what's wrong with it