# save intermediate render result to OpenEXR not working (Cycles/ v.2.79)

Tags: rendering, export, .exr

I want to render a single frame of a texture and then print it in the measurements 150x266cm at 300dpi, therefore I calculated a render resolution of 31488x17717px, which seems to be a bit of a problem with Blender.

I have tried rendering to TIFF but once it's done and I want to save it Blender crashes. Then I tried rendering to an EXR file with "Save Buffers" activated under the performance tab since I read in another thread that this will make Blender save the EXR file after each render tile is done (using single GPU) and even if Blender crashes (which t still does after finishing the last tile) I should still have a working file in my TEMP directory that I can use in Photoshop. Only thing is that no intermediate saves are being done, only a corrupted EXR file is being generated at the very end of the render process (not opening in PS and way too small).

I wonder what I am missing.

Anyone got an idea why this might be?

Thanks & greatful for any advice!

Comment: Might be not enough GPU memory or RAM, at least try CPU render. Also consider using add-ons for precise region render, like https://github.com/p2or/blender-renderborder. And then stiching small chunks in PS.

Comment: Thank you, my CPU is too slow since I have several different scenes to go through, but I guessed it must be either of these memories constraining me (vega 64 & 32gb Ram)... I hesitated from using render borders because I believed it to be not exact enough for easily stitching it back together afterwards and thought that there must be a more elegant way, but since you showed me this great add on, this will be the way to go. Especially cycling through the desired render areas by using keyframes is very useful. So, thank you very much!

Comment: It also helps to activate the "Crop" checkbox under the dimensions tab to crop the rendered frame to the defined border size (in case anyone should end up here looking for similar answers)

Comment: @Serge L sorry I hit the upvote button on your comment twice by accident and now I can't upvote your answer again :(

Comment: Nevermind, I've added actual answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Blender is crashing during super high-resolution render for whatever reason, consider using add-ons for precise region render, like [blender-renderborder](http://github.com/p2or/blender-renderborder) or [accurate-render-border](http://b3d.interplanety.org/en/accurate-render-border-add-on-v-0-0-2/) (not sure about their 2.8 compatibility) or with some [python usage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4855/29200). Enabling *Crop* in render settings can also help.

Then stich small chunks into one image in PS, Gimp or other image editor.