# Is there a way to get ONE random value as seed for Cyles per render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I know, this question sounds old, but there is a twist.

If you want to use image stacking to reduce noise, you have to choose a different seed for every render.

To do that automatically I found the following methods so far:

- using `#frame` as driver in the seed field.  This however only works if you *have* multiple frames (i.e. render an animation) - not for a single frame rendered repeatedly.
- using the small Python snippet `noise.random() * 10000`.
  This works fine for normal renders, but it screws up viewport rendering (at least in 2.71): the render never ends

Is there something, that can do both?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with rendering an animation, even if you have no keyframes? You'd just be rendering the same thing over and over, which could be stacked.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5017/599

Comment: And: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7126/599

Comment: @gandalf3 - I saw these already - thanks.

Comment: @ajwood I'm using it in the following situation:

I've an "autosave" addon running. Let's say I've completed a render after an hour and decide that it looks nice, except more samples are needed. Instead of re-rendering with more samples, I hit "render" again with the same sample settings. This way the first wait was not in vain. However I forget to increase the seed value sometimes and have to abort the second render.

The Python snippet does exactly what I need, if it wouldn't make viewport rendering unusable.

Comment: @karamike great idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a driver, use that Python snippet to set the value in the `render_pre` [application handler](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.app.handlers.html). This should stop it continuously restarting the viewport render.

Comment: Of course... Here's the [add-on](https://github.com/MStrecke/blender_random_seed) to do exactly that.