# Cycles to Luxrender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, add-on, external-applications

I am very familiar with cycles and its material nodes. Now I want to use luxrender, because it has a nice net rendering system. Is there any way to convert the cycles materials to luxrender materials?

Comment: First off, no not easily. Second: blender has many network render addons, one even comes bundled with blender.

Comment: I know. I am using lokirender now. But with  luxrender it is possible to render one frame with the power of more than one machine! What do you mean with not easily?

Comment: @rudolf97 AFAIK Luxrender does this be recording the samples taken and then combining them. You can do this in cycles by [rendering the same frame with different *seeds*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/738/599), writing these to exr files and combining them later. However this likely [isn't quite as efficient](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7126/599) as lux probably does it.

Comment: Yes I know that. But luxrender does this automated and is therefore better for animations. If you wanna render a still image, you can do it easily with cycles and combining the images.